# Neovim Automatically Uses 4 Spaces Instead of Tabs for Python

Tags: vim, neovim

Title says it all. How can I change this behaviour, so that the indentation is always a tab character and not 4 spaces?

I don't get the same issue when not editing python files.
Not that I edit many different file types, but I can at least confirm for c, plaintext and tex (as in LaTeX).

Using version 0.4.4 from the Gentoo repos.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set tab as 2 spaces in vimrc, but still set to 4 spaces when editing python files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56408989/set-tab-as-2-spaces-in-vimrc-but-still-set-to-4-spaces-when-editing-python-file)

Comment: @Matt Thanks for this; now I know which files to look at for future problems!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting `let g:python_recommended_style = 0` in your vimrc, and configuring autocmds such as `autocmd FileType python setlocal noexpandtab` if needed.

Comment: `autocmd` not necessary. Thanks for the help.